# How to Make a search bar in python flask using mongodb

Tags: python, jquery, mongodb, flask, pymongo

i tried making a search bar for my University project but i dont know where i am going wrong its giving me an error 405 in my console i am not sure but i think my search command in python flask where i want to search those products is wrong i am sorry if this question bothers you i am new to python flask and mongo db

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#livebox").on("input",function(e){
                    textinLivebox = $("#livebox").val();
                    console.log(textinLivebox)
                    $.ajax({
                        method:"post",
                        url:"/livesearch",
                        data:{text:textinLivebox},
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log(res)
                        }
                    })
                });
            })
```

python flask

```
@app.route("/livesearch")
def livesearch():
    searchbox = request.form.get("text")
    data = mongo.db.Product.find({"title"})
    result = Product.objects.all(data)
    return jsonify(result)
```

my database

```
class Product(db.Document):
    product_id  = db.IntField( unique=True)
    title       = db.StringField(max_length = 50)
    img_file    = db.StringField(nullable=False, default='static/img/dettol.jpg')
    price       = db.StringField(max_length = 50 )
    description = db.StringField( max_length = 50)
```

Comment: `405` means Method Not Allowed. Your `$.ajax` request is using `method: "post"`. If you want to receive a `POST` request, your route must support `POST`: `@app.route("/livesearch", methods=["POST"])`. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create index on text (in Mongo shell):

   ```js
   db.collection.createIndex( { name: "text", description: "text" } )
   ```
2. Use [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator to do the search (in Python code):

   ```py
   db.collection.find( { '$text': { '$search':  searchbox} } )
   ```

   You can read more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

For `405` error, you can add `POST` method in the route:

```py
@app.route("/livesearch", methods=["POST"])
```